# Error when trying to log in into application

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, symfony

I am using Laravel 10 (php 8.2) in my application as backend, and ReactJS as frontend, in production when I am trying to login, into any account, it's throwing an error.

Below is the error that is displaying.

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getPayload(): Return value must be of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag, Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag returned

This occurs only in production, but the application works fine in my local PC.
Any suggestions, what needs to be done ?

Comment: Seems to be https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/47838. [Solution](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/47834#issuecomment-1650614590) is to downgrade symphony to 6.2 for now

Comment: this is also happening with Laravel 9 https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/47840

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the error was due to this upgrade:
Upgrading symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.2.0 => v2.3.0)
(Lumen (9.1.6) (Laravel Components ^9.36.3))

**Solution:** simply run composer update again:
Upgrading symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.3.0 => v2.3.1)

in symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.3.1) the issue has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, seems like the issue is gone after upgrading !

Answer (score 1):

You need to update laravel/framework from v10.16.0 to v10.16.1 with "composer update"

More details: https://github.com/laravel/framework/compare/v10.16.0...v10.16.1